# Modify Regex to exclude *.test* files?

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I currently have this regex in my webpack config:

```
test: /\.(ts|tsx)?(\.erb)?$/,
```

However, I need it to not match files like `app/__tests__/MyComponent.test.tsx` or `app/__tests__/utils.test.ts`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `/^(?!.*\.test\.tsx?(?:\.erb)?$).*\.tsx?(?:\.erb)?$/`. Are you sure you need `(ts|tsx)?` to be optional?

Comment: You don't want files whose subdirectory is named as `__tests__` ?

Comment: @AkshayBande Either the dir itself, or just the `.test` path within the filename.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regexp feature called [negative lookbehind](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind), which makes sure that there **is no match** for a specific pattern where you want. The syntax is `(?<=_)`, where `_` is the pattern you do not want to match.

In your case, I understand you want to make sure the file doesn't end with `.test` before the extension. So, here's your final regexp :

```
(?<!.*\.test)\.(ts|tsx)?(\.erb)?$
```

You can test it on [this regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/ipWgcB/2).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it also filters out things like: `app/__tests__/utils.random.js`